# How to leverage polymorphism in MOXy POJO binding with resource JSON consumption?

Tags: json, rest, jersey, pojo, moxy

Using `Jersey 2.6`, `MOXy` as JSON provider and POJO binding.
How can one send a JSON object that would result in creation of a child class instance despite the fact that the resource method is expecting parent class instance (method parameter).

**JSON Sample**
The below sample can create a Student object and grammer wise it can be passed to the resource that accepts a Person object.

```
{"name":"Jon Doe", "grade":"Excellent"}
```

**Resource POST method**

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person test(Person student) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + student.getName());
    System.out.println("Garde: " + ((Student)student).getGrade());
    return student;
}
```

**Having the following `POJOs`** (getters and setters omitted).

```
    public class Person {
        String name;    
    } 

    public class Student extends Person {
        String grade;
    }
```

**The `Web.XML`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>TestDrive</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- 
            MOXy JSON provider is used with Jersey which is registered automatically when in classpath.
            Ref.: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy
        -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.web.main</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Edit**

1. Resource method must consume with a Person reference.
2. Person can be abstract class but not an interface (it has private non-static members).

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you need to ask you these questions :

- Why do you use `Person` as the parameter, could you use directly `Student` instead ? Depending on what your method is doing, you need to know if what you really want to retrieve is a person, or is it specifically a student. `test(Person person)` VS `test(Student student)`
- Do you want to use `Person` as a class, an abstract class or an interface ?

There are multiple solutions. I have two solutions for the case you're keeping `Person` as a normal class :

#### 1. MessageBodyReader

You can use a custom `MessageBodyReader<Person>` in order to deserialize your JSON according to your will. For example you can check if in the passing JSON, the field `grade` is present or not. If it is present, your are going to return a `Student`, if not you are returning a `Person`. Here is the code using GSON to read your JSON :

```java
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomObjectMapper implements MessageBodyReader<Person> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Person.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Person readFrom(Class<Person> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        String personName = null;
        String studentGrade = null;
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(entityStream, "UTF-8"));
        try {
            reader.beginObject();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                String name = reader.nextName();
                if (name.equals("name")) {
                    personName = reader.nextString();
                } else if (name.equals("grade")) {
                    studentGrade = reader.nextString();
                } else {
                    reader.skipValue();
                }
            }
            reader.endObject();
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        if (studentGrade != null) {
            return new Student(personName, studentGrade);
        }
        return new Person(personName);
    }
}
```

**GSON maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

#### 2. POST dedicated class

In this solution, we are going to create a new class called `PostPerson.java`. This object will be the new parameter of your method `test(PostPerson person)`. 
This class has the same behaviour as a `MessageBodyReader<Person>` except that, in my opinion, is much more readable and easier to use. However, here we are going to use Jackson instead of MOXy in order to use Jackson annotations.

**PostPerson.java**

```
public class PostPerson {

    //your actual object deserialized
    private final Person person;

    //specify which constructor to use to create a PostPerson from JSON. (By default, it is using the default constructor)
    @JsonCreator
    public PostPerson(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("grade") String grade) {
        if (grade == null) {
            person = new Person();
            person.setName(name);
        } else {
            person = new Student(name, grade);
        }
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
}
```

**Resource POST method**

```java
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person postname(PostPerson postPerson) {
    Person person = postPerson.getPerson();
    System.out.println(person.getName());
    System.out.println(((Student) person).getGrade());
    return person;
}
```

Comment: Answering the self asked questions, first question, yes, it must be Person, and second question, no, you are right, I'm changing Person to be abstract, but in this [Jackson example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638211/jackson-2-1-polymorphic-deserialization-how-to-populate-type-field-on-pojo) I tested it doesn't seem to matter much if the parent is abstract or not, do you know of a similar behavior in MOXy, I'm considering changing to Jackson it'd be easier to find support.

Comment: elegant and informative your solutions are but in Jackson it was handled without building a costume MessageBodyReader or a POST dedicated class, which is mainly what I'm trying to save time not building.

Comment: Then try to do some research about `@JsonDeserialize(as = xxx.class)`. It might be able to help you !